# How get value from dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dispatch

How to get tobacco id from `CreateTobaccoProfile` dispatch?

```js
const addToBarProfile = (data, dispatch) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var somedata = dispatch(CreateTobaccoProfile({
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  }));
  //I need id of this request to send new request
  debugger;
  resolve();
});

addToBarProfile(data, dispatch).then(x => {
  debugger;
  AttachTobaccoToBar(data._id);
});
```

Comment: If `CreateTobaccoProfile` returns a `Promise`, you can `await` for it. But I believe that it will be better to avoid and make it declarative, means that `CreateTobaccoProfile` should `dispatch` the "callback" by itself. I'm using `"` because it won't dispatch the callback itself but an action, and the "bar" (?) reducer will handle that action and will "attachTobacco" as a result.

Answer (score 0):

i think redux dispatch is sync so you can do it like this but are you sure that **CreateTobaccoProfile**

```
    CreateTobaccoProfile({
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
 })
```

Returns a value? actions are not supposed to return values they just initiate a state change

```
   const addToBarProfile = (data, dispatch) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var somedata = dispatch(
          CreateTobaccoProfile({
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
          })
        );
        //I need id of this request to send new request
        debugger;
        if (!somedata) return reject(new Error("no data found !"));
        resolve(somedata);
      });

addToBarProfile(data, dispatch).then((somedata) => {
  debugger;
  AttachTobaccoToBar(somedata._id);
});
```